# Slow windows mobile app

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

I have windows mobile application that display information from an sql server ce. Normally takes about 6 sec to load a grid of 6 rows.

Recently I realized that if I open the db on the mobile using the query analyzer tool, and then run my app everything runs about 5 times faster, then I close the query analyzer and continue using the app and everything slows down.

Did someone knows why this happens, and how can I get this performance without asking the user to open the query analyzer tool first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a database connection at application startup and keep it open for the lifttime of the application. (Do not use this connection object for anything)

Comment: That's is the recommended practice for SQL Server Compact, yes, but possibly not commonly known...